# NodeJS MongoDB $match Regex Format to JSON

Tags: regex, json, mongodb

saving a json document like

```
{
 "$match" : {
    "value" : { "$regex" : "^mystring" , "$options" : "i"}
            }
}
```

in mongodb results internally in

```
{
 "$match" : {
    "value" : /^mystring/i
            }
}
```

This seems to be not valid json anymore. E.g. if I try to send it as a Json result in nodejs I only get back this:

```
 {
"$match": {
    "value": {}
  }
 }
```

Is there a way to force the { "$regex" : "^mystring" , "$options" : "i"} syntax or another solution?

Comment: What if you stringify it before storing it? Then parse it and use it.

Comment: not the solution I was hoping for, but works ;-)